# How to render side by side videos in OculusRiftEffect or VREffect

Tags: three.js, video.js, stereo-3d

I'm experimenting with [videojs-vr](https://github.com/slawrence/videojs-vr) which is using THREE.OculusRiftEffect for rendering the video in an Oculus friendly way.

I downloaded a side by side [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjxd3TxQ-s0) from YouTube and played it within the videojs-vr example.html.

Now I'm searching for a way to show only the left part of the video in the left camera of OculusRiftEffect / VREffect and the right part for the right eye.

I think I have to find/use an event which draws the movie onto the mesh and identify which camera is currently rendered to copy only the left or the right part of the video.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Three.js I would make two spheres, one for left eye and the other one for right eye. Then separate the video using a shader on those spheres to map only half texture in each one. Then attach each sphere to one of the two cameras.

Don't sure how to do it in three.js, as I come from Unity and I'm still a noob with three, but I did exactly that in Unity. Maybe the idea helps you.